# How to write Dynamic VB.net code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, dynamic, expression-trees

For example i got a class and its got its own properties and i am passing the name of the class and the name of the property to be called to a function

Say for example exp is the variable which i am passing which contains a value = "ClassA,Property1"

```
           Function Property2BCalled(byval exp as String)

            dim classname = split(exp,",")(0)
            dim propertyname=split(exp,",")(1)
            dim value= classname.propertyname

           End Function
```

I wanna do something like that,given above.

Comment: There are few cases where this sort of thing is a good idea, and it's generally reserved for frameworks that require work-arounds to perform proxying or object creation. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: This might sound crazy well,i have a problem with localization when performing unit testing in asp.net mvc as it throws an error that virtual path cannot be found for the app_globalresources folder , and i am not able to mock it,so what i did was i dumped all the resources into a ordinary folder and from there i am accessing it but,now i need i write a if/else or select case for running through resource files i.e from which resource file i need to take the info.
so that i thought of that idea of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reflection to perform this task.
Bear in mind that reflection is Slow but it could be done.
You would enumerate the classes available in your assembly, when you find a name match, then you enumerate the properties and then Invoke the method/properties etc.

But it might be better to define an Interface and then have a common signature that your project can communicate with, then all you need is a Factory pumping out the appropriate instance of the class that is coming in your Data.

Comment: How do i get the type for the class for which i am sending the name of the class string? 
                       dim a as string=  
                                                                                
                                                                                                               GetType(className).getProperty("").Getvalue("",Nothing).Tostring()

 would be gimme the type but im sending the name of the class as string as well

Comment: For Each t As Type In [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly.GetTypes()
                    If t.Name = "yourclassname" Then
end if
next